# How to set a value on a class using another class that is called/set in main class

Tags: java, xml

I have 3 classes, say: ShareType, ShareTypesTrue and Main.

```
  public class ShareType {
        public String shareTypeName = "";
        public String noOfShare = "";
        public String parValue = "";

        public void setShareTypeName(String shareTypeName) {
            this.shareTypeName = shareTypeName;
        }

        public void setNoOfShare(String noOfShare) {
            this.noOfShare = noOfShare;
        }

        public void setParValue(String parValue) {
            this.parValue = parValue;
        }

    }

    public class ShareTypesTrue {
        public List<ShareType> shareType;

        public void setShareType(List<ShareType> shareType) {
            this.shareType = shareType;
        }

    }

    public class Main {
            ShareTypesTrue sharetypetrue = new  ShareTypesTrue();
                sharetypetrue.add(shareTypeName);
          }
```

Now my problem is i need to set shareTypeName to a value under the class ShareTypesTrue. Meaning i have to use ShareTypesTrue to call on the Sharetype class and set the shareTypeName.

Anyone has an idea?

NOTE: I cant change/add code in the first 2 classes except in main. i just need to find a way to get around this. 
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code for Main class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

 public static void main(String args[]){

    ShareTypesTrue sharetypetrue = new  ShareTypesTrue();

    //Create object
    ShareType shareType = new ShareType();
    shareType.setShareTypeName("Original Name");

    //Create list
    List<ShareType> shareTypes=new ArrayList<ShareType>();
    shareTypes.add(shareType);

    //Attach it to share
    sharetypetrue.setShareType(shareTypes);

    //Print
    for(ShareType shareTypesMember:sharetypetrue.shareType){
        System.out.println(shareTypesMember.shareTypeName);
    }

    //Editing it.
    for(ShareType shareTypesMember:sharetypetrue.shareType){
        shareTypesMember.shareTypeName = "Updated Name";
    }
    //Print
    for(ShareType shareTypesMember:sharetypetrue.shareType){
        System.out.println(shareTypesMember.shareTypeName);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Tejas, i just need to use ShareTypesTrue to set Sharetype. in main.

Comment: i think This is it. THank you soo much @Tejas

Comment: one more thing, what if i need to make another list under ShareTypesFalse?

Comment: is this ShareTypesFalse new class? If yes then answer remains same. Jsut replace variable name in for loop (below comment //Editing it.) with name of your new list.
If it is not a new class then you have to extend existing class ShareTypesTrue and then create new list in it and repeat above procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sharetype class to set the shareTypeName

```
ShareType share = new ShareType();
share.setShareTypeName("name");
share.setNoOfShare("no");
share.setParValue("val");

List<ShareType> shareType = new ArrayList<ShareType>();
shareType.add(share);
```

use ShareTypesTrue to set Sharetype

```
ShareTypesTrue sharetrue = new  ShareTypesTrue();
sharetrue.setShareType(shareType);//pass ShareType as list
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @satya yes i need to use ShareTypesTrue to set ShareType Values. This on you suggested didnt seem to work. it says it cannot be resolved to a variable. can you give me example on how do i set each variable in ShareType using ShareTypesTrue? Thank you

Comment: @KelvinPeralta `it says it cannot be resolved to a variable` I'm not getting with this. This is the example what you need.

Comment: i dont seem to get it. i also have the imports of arraylist and list.

Comment: @KelvinPeralta, just clarify which error ar you getting

Comment: I got it already, Thanks to @Tejas, Thanks to you too for helping out sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the 'name' in ShareType, what prevents you from doing the below:

```
class ShareTypeTrue_Extended extends ShareTypeTrue{

 protected shareTypeName;

 public ShareTypeTrue_Extended(String shareTypeName){this.shareTypeName=shareTypeName;}

 public void setShareType(List<ShareType> shareType) {

        for(ShareType s: shareType)s.setShareTypeName(this.shareTypeName);
        super.setShareType(shareType);
    }

}
```